# jhipster kubernetes deployment has no redis

Tags: kubernetes, redis, jhipster

i have designed several microservices using JHipster jdl studio, with redis cache.
i want to deploy them using kubernetes and docker-compose JHipster  generator.

With docker-compose deployement generation, i see redis docker in the  generated docker-compose.yml.
But in kubernetes no redis srvice or app generated.

I read the jhipster kubernetes generator source, but i dont see any redis generation in jhipster kubernetes generators and templates

Is there an issue or is there a reason for that?

thanks a lot

here is a sample of one microservice
app.jdl

```
application {
  config {
    applicationType microservice
    authenticationType jwt
    baseName msbooklibrary
    blueprints []
    buildTool maven
    cacheProvider redis
    clientPackageManager npm
    creationTimestamp 1606242682385
    databaseType sql
    devDatabaseType h2Memory
    dtoSuffix DTO
    embeddableLaunchScript false
    enableHibernateCache true
    enableSwaggerCodegen true
    enableTranslation false
    jhiPrefix jhi
    jhipsterVersion "6.10.5"
    languages [en, fr]
    messageBroker kafka
    nativeLanguage en
    otherModules []
    packageName fr.XXXX
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
    searchEngine elasticsearch
    serverPort 9000
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka
    skipClient true
    skipUserManagement true
    testFrameworks [gatling, cucumber]
    websocket false
  }

  entities Book
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
  msbooklibrary:
    image: msbooklibrary
    environment:
      - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
      - 'SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger'
      - MANAGEMENT_METRICS_EXPORT_PROMETHEUS_ENABLED=true
      - 'EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka'
      - 'SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config'
      - 'SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://msbooklibrary-postgresql:5432/msbooklibrary'
      - 'JHIPSTER_CACHE_REDIS_SERVER=redis://msbooklibrary-redis:6379'
      - JHIPSTER_CACHE_REDIS_CLUSTER=false
      - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30
      - 'SPRING_DATA_JEST_URI=http://msbooklibrary-elasticsearch:9200'
      - 'SPRING_ELASTICSEARCH_REST_URIS=http://msbooklibrary-elasticsearch:9200'
      - 'KAFKA_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS=kafka:9092'
      - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=admin
  msbooklibrary-postgresql:
    image: 'postgres:12.3'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=msbooklibrary
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
  msbooklibrary-elasticsearch:
    image: 'docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.8'
    environment:
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
      - discovery.type=single-node
  msbooklibrary-redis:
    image: 'redis:6.0.4'
```

msbooklibrary-deployment.yml // kubernetes

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: msbooklibrary
  namespace: msdmall
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: msbooklibrary
      version: 'v1'
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: msbooklibrary
        version: 'v1'
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchExpressions:
                    - key: app
                      operator: In
                      values:
                        - msbooklibrary
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
              weight: 100
      initContainers:
        - name: init-ds
          image: busybox:latest
          command:
            - '/bin/sh'
            - '-c'
            - |
              while true
              do
                rt=$(nc -z -w 1 msbooklibrary-postgresql 5432)
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                  echo "DB is UP"
                  break
                fi
                echo "DB is not yet reachable;sleep for 10s before retry"
                sleep 10
              done
      containers:
        - name: msbooklibrary-app
          image: dockerregistry/msbooklibrary
          env:
            - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
              value: prod
            - name: SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI
              value: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry.msdmall.svc.cluster.local:8761/config
            - name: JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: registry-secret
                  key: registry-admin-password
            - name: EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE
              value: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry.msdmall.svc.cluster.local:8761/eureka/
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
              value: jdbc:postgresql://msbooklibrary-postgresql.msdmall.svc.cluster.local:5432/msbooklibrary
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
              value: msbooklibrary
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: msbooklibrary-postgresql
                  key: postgresql-password
            - name: SPRING_DATA_JEST_URI
              value: http://msbooklibrary-elasticsearch.msdmall.svc.cluster.local:9200
            - name: SPRING_ELASTICSEARCH_REST_URIS
              value: http://msbooklibrary-elasticsearch.msdmall.svc.cluster.local:9200
            - name: KAFKA_CONSUMER_KEY_DESERIALIZER
              value: 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer'
            - name: KAFKA_CONSUMER_VALUE_DESERIALIZER
              value: 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer'
            - name: KAFKA_CONSUMER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
              value: 'jhipster-kafka.msdmall.svc.cluster.local:9092'
            - name: KAFKA_CONSUMER_GROUP_ID
              value: 'msbooklibrary'
            - name: KAFKA_CONSUMER_AUTO_OFFSET_RESET
              value: 'earliest'
            - name: KAFKA_PRODUCER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
              value: 'jhipster-kafka.msdmall.svc.cluster.local:9092'
            - name: KAFKA_PRODUCER_KEY_DESERIALIZER
              value: 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer'
            - name: KAFKA_PRODUCER_VALUE_DESERIALIZER
              value: 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer'
            - name: SPRING_SLEUTH_PROPAGATION_KEYS
              value: 'x-request-id,x-ot-span-context'
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: ' -Xmx256m -Xms256m'
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: '512Mi'
              cpu: '500m'
            limits:
              memory: '1Gi'
              cpu: '1'
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 9000
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /management/health
              port: http
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            periodSeconds: 15
            failureThreshold: 6
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /management/health
              port: http
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
```

msbooklibrary-service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: msbooklibrary
  namespace: msdmall
  labels:
    app: msbooklibrary
spec:
  selector:
    app: msbooklibrary
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 9000
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't recall any specific reason. Guess it was just forgotten. Can you [open an issue on github](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=FEATURE_REQUEST.md)?